# Detect if 'High contrast' is enabled in Android accessibility settings

Tags: android, accessibility

How can I detect if 'High Contrast' setting (available on Android 5.0+) is enabled in Accessibility settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `AccessibilityManager` class ([see source here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a4725ef/core/java/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager.java)) you have a public method called `isHighTextContrastEnabled` that you can use to get your information:

```
/**
 * Returns if the high text contrast in the system is enabled.
 * <p>
 * <strong>Note:</strong> You need to query this only if you application is
 * doing its own rendering and does not rely on the platform rendering pipeline.
 * </p>
 *
 * @return True if high text contrast is enabled, false otherwise.
 *
 * @hide
 */
public boolean isHighTextContrastEnabled() {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        IAccessibilityManager service = getServiceLocked();
        if (service == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return mIsHighTextContrastEnabled;
    }
}
```

So in your code, you can access this method by doing so (if you're in an `Activity`):

```
AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
boolean isHighTextContrastEnabled = am.isHighTextContrastEnabled();
```

Comment: Not sure why, but isHighTextContrastEnabled() is undefined for AccessibilityManager in my case.

Comment: Just found out that the method is @hide method, so really shouldn't be able to invoke directly like this. Need to invoke it by reflection way.

Comment: This can not help me much more.

Answer (score 4):

- @alxscms' answer may be right but it does not help me So I found an *alternative way* to check **High contrast text** is Enabled or not in android.

> Below function will return true if HighContrastText is enabled in user phone and otherwise return false.

> Below function is checked in all android phones and it's working.

```
public static boolean isHighContrastTextEnabled(Context context) {
    if (context != null) {
        AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
        Method m = null;

        if (am != null) {
            try {
                m = am.getClass().getMethod("isHighTextContrastEnabled", null);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                Log.i("FAIL", "isHighTextContrastEnabled not found in AccessibilityManager");
            }
        }

        Object result;
        if (m != null) {
            try {
                result = m.invoke(am, null);
                if (result instanceof Boolean) {
                    return (Boolean) result;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("fail", "isHighTextContrastEnabled invoked with an exception" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

> > **I hope this can help many more others.**

Answer (score 3):

we can check highContrast fonts like this

```
public boolean isHighTextContrastEnabled(Context context) {
    return Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "high_text_contrast_enabled", 0) == 1;
}
```