# Enabling 'High Contrast Text' mode from within Android/Java using AccessibilityManager

Tags: java, android, text, contrast

I've reviewed this thread on how to get the current status of the 'High Contrast Text' mode by calling :  isHighTextContrastEnabled from within AccessibilityManager.

See this thread:
[Detect if 'High contrast' is enabled in Android accessibility settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411712/detect-if-high-contrast-is-enabled-in-android-accessibility-settings)

Is there a way one can use AccessibilityManager to enable the 'Hight Contrast Text' mode from within an application?

Looking at the available methods I didn't see anything.

Comment: What about `/**
     * Sets the current state and notifies listeners, if necessary.
     *
     * @param stateFlags The state flags.
     */
    private void setStateLocked(int stateFlags) {`

That uses the `stateFlags` for setting `final boolean highTextContrastEnabled =
                (stateFlags & STATE_FLAG_HIGH_TEXT_CONTRAST_ENABLED) != 0;`

Comment: I don't fully understand some of the context of your answer ( "That uses the stateFlags for setting" )

Comment: @Abhijeet - can you elaborate with contextual example?

Comment: I am able to successfully get the status of the High Contrast Text boolean value, but I am not able to set it yet.  The method is private and I'm wondering if I have to use reflection or not?

Comment: I now have the following code but I am getting a "no method exception".  What do you think?

Comment: AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
        Class accessibilityClass = am.getClass();
        Method m1 = null;
        Method m2 = null;
        try {
            m1 = accessibilityClass.getDeclaredMethod("setStateLocked",null);
            m2 = accessibilityClass.getMethod("setStateLocked",null);

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No such method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();