# How to ignore High Contrast Accessibility option in Android during canvas drawing?

Tags: android, canvas

I have a custom view that I want to have colored text. But when the `high contrast` option is enabled canvas ignores all paint's color settings and draws text as black and white (`drawText` overloads)

It is somewhat possible to detect if this option is enabled(via reflection, etc).
Is there a way to ignore that for some views?

PS I know about the switch in settings, that's not a solution.

Comment: I have the exact same question. I don't want text in canvas affected by this setting. This is happening only on Android 9.0+. On Android 8 canvas text is not affected.

Comment: same question. Have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

My workaround looks something like this:

```
public void drawTextWithoutHighContrastEffects(Canvas canvas, String text, float x, float y, Paint paint)
{
    if (isHighContrastTextEnabled)
    {
        Path path = new Path();
        paint.getTextPath(text, 0, text.length(), x, y, path);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    } else {
        canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
    }
}
```

Please note that this is a simplified solution, e.g. `path` instance should not be recreated for each draw operation, create once and then reuse it. Also `paint` object should be set up correctly with `FILL` style in order to make the text drawn using `drawPath` look the same as drawn by `drawText`.

The value of `isHighContrastTextEnabled` flag comes from here: [Detect if 'High contrast' is enabled in Android accessibility settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411712/detect-if-high-contrast-is-enabled-in-android-accessibility-settings)

Answer (score 0):

to force prevent view from adapting to accessibility settings you can set in XML

```
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```

or you can set in code

```
view.setImportantForAccessibility(IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
```

to detect if user have High Contrast Text option enabled you can check this link ([Detect if 'High contrast' is enabled in Android accessibility settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411712/detect-if-high-contrast-is-enabled-in-android-accessibility-settings))

Comment: Didn't work for me on OnePlus 5. Tried both IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO and IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS
on the view or its parent. Tried both programmatic and static approaches.

Comment: As they say in the docs:
"Note: While not recommended, an accessibility service may decide to ignore this attribute and operate on all views in the view tree."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:importantForAccessibility